# Visual Studio Qt Add-in errors about Qt versions that had been removed long ago

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt5, qt-vs-addin

I have
Visual Studio 2019 Professional
Qt 5.15.1 & 6.0.0 beta for msvc 2019

Previous versions of Visual Studio were completely removed before installing VS 2019.

That error Visual Studio shows when I open menu ***Extensions -> Qt VS Tools -> Qt Options***:
[image]

As a text:

> Qt VS Tools
> The following error occurred:
>
> These Qt version are inaccessible:
> 5.4 msvc2012_opengl in  msvc2010_opengl in  msvc2017 in  msvc_2017 in  Make sure that you have read access to all files in your Qt
> directories.

These versions of Qt had been removed long ago.

And what is shown when attempt to add actual versions in Qt Options:

[image]

> Qt VS Tools
>
> The following error occurred:
>
> Error registering Qt version.

How I can fix these errors and where the history of these long ago removed Qt versions is stored?